# Single Activity APP with ACTION_VIEW

Tags: android

I just need to make an app that when executed it just links you to a website.

I have searched around and this question has already been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199791/create-android-app-that-acts-as-a-shortcut-to-our-mobile-site), but I am having "unfortunately ___ has stopped." I know it is a simple app, and it must be something small, but I still haven't been able to figure it out.

here is my .java code

```
package com.xyz.abc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ContinentalActivity extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,                    Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
     startActivity(myIntent); 
    }
 }
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.chca.onbile"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk  android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ContinentalActivity" >
        <intent-filter>


        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your error.