# android make shortcut stay after uninstall

Tags: android, url, package, shortcut

As far as I understand if an app creates a shortcut on home screen the status of the shortcut changes depending on what kind of shortcut it is.

- a shortcut to an app (by package name) would be deleted when the app creating it disappears
- a shortcut containing a url to be viewed stays after deletion of the creating app.

my question is how to keep a shortcut to an app on home screen after the creating app is uninstalled?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why would you want to do this? I mean you would get some kind of error message if you try to open an app that is not installed (if this is even possible).

Comment: i knew i wasn't clear enough :( Just to make things clearer i meant the shortcut to open a different application than the one installing it, like Goog'a maps or something

Comment: Ah, OK. That clarifies things. To be hornest, I've got no clue, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This stack shows how to create the shortcut you want.
[Create Android App That Acts As A Shortcut To Our Mobile Site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199791/create-android-app-that-acts-as-a-shortcut-to-our-mobile-site)

When an app is uninstalled manually, I don't think there's a way to make it install something else at the same time.