# HTML5 webapp discovery, shortcut and push-notification App?

Tags: android, ios, app-store, apple-push-notifications, google-play

I was thinking would it be possible to create native application that would serve the purpose of only few things:
1) When you open application it takes you to URL defined by applications config. (like a bookmarked shortcut on home screen)
2) Allows people to discover the "app" on the store whether it is Apple store or Google play
3) It would allow me to send push-notifications to people and direct them to correct URL to see the recieved message and/or updates. (i.e. I own social site and person that downloads that app is allowed to sign in. When he gets new message that "fake app" would display notification with option to view message and that option should open web page - kinda redirect user)

These are the concerns that I think webapp lacks (don't start flame about HTML5 performance or offline capabilities - these are not issue). I think that many app users don't care/can't tell the difference between whether they are using native app or they are on the web (if it feels like native app). I believe that for such users it should be enough to provide ability to discover "app" (2) and "install it on home screen".

Is this scenario possible? If not what could be the road-blocks?

Comment: If you want to receive push notifications etc. you will still need to build some kind of native app though but what you suggest is feasible. The only thing is what user expectations will be if they are downloading an app and find it just re-directs to your web site. An alternative could be to do a PhoneGap app that includes a mobile interface but heavily uses web views within to save effort.

Comment: I know about phonegap, but I only need "shortcut" on home screen, so it's not a problem with UX right now. I'm only brainstorming about the  idea itself.

Comment: Shortcut is easy to do, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199791/create-android-app-that-acts-as-a-shortcut-to-our-mobile-site but you would still need to build in other parts to the native app for the push notifications, i.e. it needs to be checking for push notifications and showing these to the user. So it is more than just a shortcut.